# build dinamic chart dashboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts

I have a backend with a REST api from witch I want to build a dashboard with diferent filters etc. I check around chart.js d3.js... My JSON have this structure:

```
[{ 
  id: 33, location: 'Madrid', 
  value: 2.34, 
  country: 'Spain', 
  createdAt: '01/01/2017 11:44' 
}, { 
  id: 34, 
  location: 'Biarritz', 
  value: 3.45, 
  country: 'France', 
  createdAt: '01/02/2017 11:44' 
}]
```

What I need is to present some charts (it's easy with chart.js) but is there something out of the box with filters (live)? I mean, make the chart dinamically refresh selecting a range of date for example, or selecting a country etc...
Other way... I have to options:

- write everything in JS and refresh my chars
- write a new api to filter my data

any help¿?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about backend task?

Comment: I did the backend for a mobile app, this json is what GET returns. What I need is to build a front with charts. I'm asking if there is something giving this json buits some charts with filters (country, location, date range) or if I have to create a custom backend with this kind of filters

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on the amount of expected data.

In case if the amount is low, the scenario might be the following:

- you return all the data from backend
- front end simply filters it the way you need

On the other hand, if you have a lot of data:

- you add some param 'filter' and use it during querying database